# Android emulator unable to run the app

Tags: android

I am trying to run my app on emulator, but it is unable to run the app. It is showing "Launching appname" in progress bar but unable to run on emulator. Please help me, I tried a lot. But not working.
[image]

Comment: Have you created your AVD with correct configurations??

Comment: yes I did it correctly

Comment: check your emulator running or not using adb commands..

Comment: adb shell commands not working, what to do?

Comment: what you tried?? what happen?? check this link for commands: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCommandLine/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more than one eclipse installations. Remove one and it will work for sure. I also solved like the same.

Answer (score 0):

restart adb

```
adb stop-server
adb start-server
```

I would suggest you use [genymotion](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://www.genymotion.com/&ei=hKImU9bgPMOJrQeD0oCoBg&usg=AFQjCNFTHXzLRxwI9XnHTZ1RWw_3Oq3Vbw&bvm=bv.62922401,d.bmk)

Its almost as fast as device

Comment: It needs license, not free

Comment: you try the free version not the paid version